# How to convert a Python dict to a Class object

Tags: python, type-safety

I am looking for a simple way to directly convert a python dict to a custom object as follows, while not breaking intellisense. The result should not be read-only, it should behave just like a new object.

```
d = {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2
}

class MyObject(object):
    key1 = None
    key2 = None

# convert to object o

# after conversion
# should be able to access the defined props
# should be highlighted by intellisense
print(o.key1)
# conversion back to dict is plain simple
print(o.__dict__)
```

Comment: `for key, value in d.items(): setattr(o, key, value)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your object has no fields, just class attributes. You need to create a `__init__` method, some will call it a constructor but it is not actually a constructor as understood by other languages so lets avoid calling it like that.

```py
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, d=None):
        if d is not None:
            for key, value in d.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)

d = {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
}

o = MyObject(d)
```

Note: the above code will try to set all key-value pairs in the dict to fields in the object. Some valid keys such as `"key.1"` will not be valid field names (it will actually be set but you will not be able to get it with `o.key.1`).

Comment: Just that it requires the creation of a new object like this `o = MyObject({})` which is no big problem but can it be avoided?

Comment: Sure, does my updated answer fulfill your requirements? `o = MyObject()` should work fine now.

Comment: @AlexPredescu you will probably want to do some key checks inside the loop before the `setattr` call to find characters that you do not want (such as `.`). In case performance and memory usage is an important factor, knowing the keys that the dicts will have would allow as to use `__slots__`.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (requires Python 3.7+):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MyObject:
    key1: int = None
    key2: int = None


d = {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
}

o = MyObject(**d)

print(o)  # MyObject(key1=1, key2=2)
print(vars(o))  # {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

`dataclass` will automatically generate `__repr__`, `__eq__`,  `__hash__`, and some other methods for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
dict_ = {"User" :{"Name" : "SQWiperYT", "ID" : 10, "Other" : {"ID" : 1}}}
import json


class OurObject:
    def __init__(self, /, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        keys = sorted(self.__dict__)
        items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in keys)
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
      
      
x = json.dumps(dict_)
y = json.loads(x, object_hook=lambda d: OurObject(**d))

# See How it Works
y.User
>>> OurObject(ID=10, Name='SQWiperYT', Other=OurObject(ID=1))
y.User.ID
>>> 10
y.User.Name
>>> 'SQWiperYT'
y.User.Other.ID
>>> 1
```

This is the thing you need actually.

Comment: Please consider explaining your solution and why does it solve the problem.

Comment: note for the future: you overcomplicate it too much

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 0):

a slightly modified example based on the article https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/14/python-101-how-to-change-a-dict-into-a-class/

```
class Dict2Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for key in dictionary:
            setattr(self, key, dictionary[key])
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<dict2obj: %s>" % self.__dict__

ball_dict = {"color":"blue", "size":8, "material":"rubber", "other": {"speed": 15, "mass": 1.2 }}
ball = Dict2Obj(ball_dict)
print (ball)
```

the nested dicctionary is not converted into a class itself. It is a similar result as the solution using dataclass but without having `__eq__` and `__hash__`